# Android: Adding Navigation Drawer in an old project

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, libraries

Hello I have a problem when I try to add a Naviagtion Drawer using **Eclipse** to an old project. The project **targetSDK** is 21 and **minSDK** 14. 
The **Project Build Target** is 5.0.1.

Happens that I want to add the next piece of code to my main_activity.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

And the problem that I have is: error: No resource identifier found for attribute '**headerLayout**' (also problem with '**menu**').

There's some post with the same trouble but I don't want to migrate to Android Studio if not necessary and I do not understand what's happening.

I have to import some library?

I have tried to create another project succesfully with the same code and same settings excepts that I change the Project Build Target's value to 2.3.1. I tried to change it in the project but then I have a lot of troubles.

Any help please?
Do you need anything else to know to be able to help?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing:

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: I have it. It's included on <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout... /> definition